# Checking if looped item has a parent inside a shortcode

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode

all I want is to check if the custom post item in the loop has a parent. I am using this inside a shortcode. I could not find how to access the property from inside the loop.

Thank you my dears

```
$q = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',

    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'category' => '',
));

while ($q->have_posts()) {
      $q->the_post();
      ... <- Check if the loop item has a parent
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`WP_Post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/) class has an attribute `post_parent` that you can use for this.

```
while ($q->have_posts()) {
      $q->the_post();
      $post = get_post();
      if (!empty($post->post_parent)) {
          // do something different
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me a ton.